# 0 or 1 combinations such that we do not have two 1's immediately in sequence

Tags: c++

My requirement is for a code to find the number of combinations of two digits only 0 and 1 for X digit size which may vary from 1 .. 1000 such that no time two 1 can be immediately in sequence but 0's are possible

Say for input of 4 digit we have

```
1010 1000 0000 0101 0001 0010 0100 1001
```

I am not sure which of algos to generate such a combinations of 0's and 1's?

Comment: Well actually I am not getting the logic so in need to seek some advice - if once can specify the approach I can do the coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is given by the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

Here are the first few results:

```
length     number of combinations
1          2   (0, 1)
2          3   (00, 01, 10)
3          5   (000, 001, 010, 100, 101)
4          8   (0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 0101, 1000, 1001, 1010)
```

You can see the why there is a relationship to the Fibonacci sequence if you consider strings starting with "0" or "10" separately:

```
  number of sequences of n digits
= number of sequences starting with 0, followed by n-1 more digits
+ number of sequences starting with 10, followed by n-2 more digits
```

Sequences starting with "11" are disallowed.

The Fibonacci numbers can be calculated very quickly if an appropriate technique is used, but you should be aware that the answer will grow very quickly as `maxlen` increases. If you want to have an exact answer you will need to use a library that can work with arbitrary large integers.

Comment: One question: did you know of this relation, or did you just happen to see that they are the same. Hats off to you in either case. :)

Comment: I understood the Fibonnaci Sequence where F(n) series is the sum of its previous two in sequence with seed value as 0 and 1 but not able to understand the length and combinations stuff - how is it derived?

Comment: @Prakash: `number of combinations = F(X + 2)`

Comment: That's great any mathematical explanation for same: 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8

F(4) = F(6) = 8

Comment: @vhallac: I've seen similar problems before, and they can usually be solved with recurrence relationships. I tried to write the recurrence relationship and noticed it looked familiar.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to build the complete string by using the words `10` and `0` (and `1`, but only at the very end).

```
build(sofar, maxlen):
  if len(sofar) > maxlen: return
  if len(sofar) == maxlen: found(sofar); return
  if len(sofar) == maxlen - 1: build(sofar + "1", maxlen)
  build(sofar + "10", maxlen)
  build(sofar + "0", maxlen)
```

The proof that this algorithm only generates valid sequences is left to you. Same with the proof that this algorithm generates *all* valid sequences.

Comment: I was thinking of counting normally, then replacing each `1` with `01`, and finally throwing out the excess on the most significant part. But was having problem with repetitions. This is nicer. :)

Comment: I think this algorithm might be slow for maxlen = 1000.

Comment: Indeed. Your answer is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a function that generates these values into arrays, and another function that just checks if the current index to a value in the array is a '1' and checks if the next value is a '1' or not? If true, then discard; else, valid.